# Как решить задачу о быках, коровах и телятах на Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Бык стоит 10 рублей, корова - 5 рублей, телёнок - 0.5 рублей. Необходимо на 100 рублей купить 100 голов скота. Мне стало интересно, как такую задачу решить в Haskell? В императивных языках задача решается через вложенные циклы, но в Haskell их нет. Сколько ни пытался, решить задачу не смог.

Comment: [List comprehension](https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension) как вариант

Answer (score 2):

Код:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    print [(b, k, c) |
        b <- [1..10],
        k <- [1..20],
        c <- [1..200],
        (\x y z ->
             10 * x + 5 * y + 0.5 * z == 100 && x + y + z == 100)
        b k c]
```

---

Пояснения:

1. `10 * x + 5 * y + 0.5 * z == 100` - предикат для проверки общей стоимости скота
2. `x + y + z == 100` - предикат для проверки общей численности скота

---

P.S. В Haskell новичек, прошу за код сильно не ругать.